# Implementing SELU activation in TFlite micro

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I hope to be able to use SELU activation in a CNN model for deployment on a MCU using TFlite micro.

The SELU is just a scaled version of the ELU, and ELU is implemented as one of the kernels in TFLite micro.

I'we implemented SELU based of a copy of `/lite/micro/kernels/elu.cc` and `/lite/micro/kernels/elu.h` as `selu.cc` and `selu.h`.
For `int8` operations, the calculations in `SeluEval()` are just returned from a lookup table, that is calculated and filled during `SeluPrepare()`

From reading https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom it's still unclear to me,  what is required to allow the **TFLiteMicro** port to pick up my SELU activation, and wether all of the **TFLite** framwork, that seems to sit on top of TFLite micro also needs to be able to pick it up to sucessfully convert and quantize my model ?

From what i can see in the TFLite micro port all **builtin** ops are registered in the `all_ops_resolver.cc` as well as `micro_mutable_op_resolver.h` adding my custum op here might be a hack to move on, if nessecery.

Has anyone sucessfully implemented a **custom op**, in TFLite Micro and is able to point me in a direction on how this should be done ?

Alternatively is there additional information on the process availible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom op to TFLu runtime with [`MicroMutableOpResolver`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5ecbbd87a4556e06cbb3dcf384d088dd27fce4e0/tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_mutable_op_resolver.h#L82). The [test code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_mutable_op_resolver_test.cc) contains minimal example of how this can be done. If you register selu with it's custom name, you would be able to use it for your runtime.

If the space allows you can use ['AllOpsResolver`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.h) and add your custom op.

Comment: The SELU has a different scale depending on wether the value is above or below 0, given by

Comment: the TFLite micro `elu` is :

`return value < 0.0 ? std::exp(value) - 1.0f : value;`
For the `elu` to conform to the desired shape,  scaling below 0 is different, as per

`def elu(z, alpha=1):
    return np.where(z < 0, alpha * (np.exp(z) - 1), z)`

`def selu(z, scale=scale_0_1, alpha=alpha_0_1):
    return scale * elu(z, alpha)`

With:
`a = 1.6732632423543778
b = 1.0507009873554805`
Thus the builtin `elu` cannot be stretched to accomodate this

Comment: Oh I got the point. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: I think i got that part right, i've added it on `micro_ops.h` also in `flatbuffer_conversions.cc`. However somthing in TFLite is still missing it seems

`RuntimeError: Failed to initialize op resolver for calibration:`
`There are unresolved custom ops: [Selu]Encountered unresolved custom op:` `Selu.Node number 1 (Selu) failed to prepare.`

Comment: Model and full output availible here https://gist.github.com/opprud/ec879d365cf6a62a1117b2c22f3279da

Comment: Usually adding Flex delegate would do, but for full int8 operation you'd need to add your Custom op resolver (for TFLite kernel) as documented in https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom#register_the_operator_with_the_kernel_library. It tells you to add registration to python interpreter wrapper in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/interpreter_wrapper.cc.